# Firebase authentication resetPassword

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I am creating simple registration using react JS and Firebase.
I want to send a custom action handler using Firebase. How I implement the given below link using react JS.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: That link has lots of sample JavaScript code that should work in any framework. Did you try anything already? If so, can you show where you got stuck?

Comment: thanks in advance @FrankvanPuffelen i am stuck when i am sending password reset email to user with
https://user-registration-6b9cd.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=K7sZl7rzVvZVOMUIEKGWpVPcLIpVkQ0QXH_Ii_gkS5AAAAF3SmFK6w&apiKey=AIzaSyAtFPwPxGhyKFZt03DycmrVxK2FpfiJvYM&lang=en 

i just want to change https://user-registration-6b9cd.firebaseapp.com with localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

seeing your comment I will add the way in answer to route traffic to your custom handler.
for custom email action handler you would have to create your own handlers (using HTML and js , react app , flutter anything you want) after doing that you can either test your handler by routing traffic to it (localhost) using ngrok(that will provide you with https url to route traffic on localhost, preferred method for testing) , or you can deploy it and directly use that url . now with that url go to firebase(your project) -> authentication -> templates -> use whatever handler you want( example reset password or email verification) -> edit and add custom action url to route traffic to your handler( hosted(deployed) or local(ngrok routing) .